# How to convert DWORD to Hex

Tags: windows, hex, dword

I've searched a lot and found nothing useful regarding this thing.
If anyone knows please share the knowledge.

Problem: I have a DWORD "-476053499" and I want to convert it to hex (e.g. XX XX XX XX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DWORD is just a typedef for a a 32-bit unsigned integer (e.g. `unsigned int` or `uint32_t`).  Notice that it's "unsigned", so I'm not sure how that plays into your value of `-476053499`

You didn't specify which language, but to convert a DWORD to a hexadecimal string is easily accomplished like this in C:

```
DWORD dwValue = (DWORD)(-476053499);
char szHexString[20];
sprintf(szHexString, "%X");  // use %x if you want lowercase hex
```

Equivalent in C++:

```
DWORD dwValue = (DWORD)(-476053499);
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << dwValue;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

If your original value is actually a string, and not a DWORD, then to convert it to a number is simply:

```
const char* s = "-476053499";
DWORD value = (DWORD)atoi(s);
```